# set depot path from a terminal using p4 command

Tags: perforce, p4v

I have recently start using perforce.

in my organization we have tool that translates installation path to depot path where repos are , I want to know if we can set that translated path in the already open perforce from the commandline ?

which in turn also brings perforce (p4v) in focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perforce's solution for this is `P4CONFIG`.  Do:

```
p4 set P4CONFIG=p4config.txt
```

Then, in the path you want to associate with a particular server ("repo" in gitspeak), create a file called `p4config.txt` that contains:

```
P4PORT=your_server:1666
```

The `P4CONFIG` file can also contain values for `P4USER`, `P4CLIENT`, etc.

It sounds like your tool should simply be modified to write its information to `P4CONFIG` files so that Perforce client tools can pick the information up automatically.  Failing that, you might be able to script something around this tool that queries it and then converts its output to `P4CONFIG` settings.

Comment: Samwise, this does not answer his initial question. I'm trying to do a similar thing. His problem is that he wants to take a path and have p4v focus that path on the opened p4v client. That is similar to the "Show in depot" functionality.

Comment: @RyanGlenn That's just `p4v -s FILENAME` AFAIK?  (See `p4v -help` for command-line flags to P4V.)